# .HTACCESS url rewrite - 4 simple rewrite rules are not working (GoDaddy+WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**I wonder if my rewrite rules are incorrect since they are not working on my Godaddy shared server?**

I have four very basic .htaccess URL rewrite rules.
Whenever the user types/clicks on the link:

1. Beautiful SEO (desired) link `http://www.electriccarlos.com/albums/`

   is actually `http://www.electriccarlos.com/type/audio/`
2. Beautiful SEO (desired) link `http://www.electriccarlos.com/discography/` 

   is actually `http://www.electriccarlos.com/type/audio/`
3. Beautiful SEO (desired) link `http://www.electriccarlos.com/gallery/` 

   is actually `http://www.electriccarlos.com/type/gallery/`
4. Beautiful SEO (desired) link `http://www.electriccarlos.com/videos/` 

   is actually `http://www.electriccarlos.com/type/video/`

---

### .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN Omar Juvera
RewriteEngine On
    # albums
RewriteRule    ^albums/?$       type/audio/     [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^discography/?$  type/audio/     [NC,L]
    # gallery
RewriteRule    ^gallery/?$      type/gallery/   [NC,L]
    # videos
RewriteRule    ^videos/?$       type/video/     [NC,L]
# END Omar Juvera


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

---

The `.htaccess` file is properly configured and `RedirectMatch` is active.

Comment: Have you confirmed that mod_rewrite is enabled/working? `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive (which is enabled by default). You also shouldn't mix redirects/rewrites from both modules.

Comment: I am running WordPress. It's redirect works

Comment: Ah, if you have WP, you have other directives? Where are you putting these directives - we'll probably need to see your entire `.htaccess` file. Are these pages inside of WordPress?

Comment: @w3dk Updated the question (htaccess section)

Comment: @w3dk By using [templatemonster.com](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-check-whether-mod_rewrite-is-enabled-on-server.html#gref) instructions, I can confirm that mod_rewrite is active

Comment: Yeah, if you have WP running with pretty URLs (no `index.php` in them) then mod_rewrite is enabled. Are these WP pages - I assume they are? I think the problem here is that whilst you are _internally rewriting_ `/albums` to `/type/audio/`, WordPress still sees the URL as `/albums` (the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), so unless `/albums` is a routable URL in WP, it will still fail. Can you not change the URL in WP? Try (temporarily) changing it to an external redirect (adding the `R` flag is sufficient since you have `RewriteBase` set).

Comment: @w3dk You got it a bit wrong. I do not want a redirect. I want a url rewite. Meaning, if I type `http://www.electriccarlos.com/gallery/` the url will remain as such and will show page `http://www.electriccarlos.com/type/gallery/` The R will not work, it won't do what I want. It literally redirects and changes the url to `http://www.electriccarlos.com/type/gallery/`

Comment: The "redirect" wasn't a solution. That was just a demo/debugging/testing exercise. If the redirect does "work" (ie. it redirects to `/type/gallery` and the page is served), but the rewrite does not then the problem is with how WP routes the URL (as I mentioned in my comment above and in SuperDupperApps's answer below).

Comment: @w3dk The redirect [R] worked

Comment: @Omar yes but it changed what was displayed in the browser. It's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, anything that you do in your top rules is simply being overwritten by the WordPress: `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

Which rewrites everything to `/index.php` except for existing files and directories.

You're going to have to speak very nicely to WordPress and ask it to do this for you! If you don't know how to do that I suggest starting another question about how to do this with WordPress.

Comment: I agree (+1) Unless there is another way to route URLs in WordPress? "I assume that WordPress is working off the original request, rather than REQUEST_URI" - Rather confusingly, the `REQUEST_URI` PHP variable (ie. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), as opposed to the `REQUEST_URI` Apache variable, is the _original request_. PHP could potentially access `REDIRECT_URL` in this situation, but I don't think WP does?

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'm assuming not due to the results the OP is getting. It's usually best to work with your CMS in these situations anyway, so that the internal links are correct too. It's not much good making your nice URLs work if the CMS continues to generate the old ones.

Comment: I updated my answer to remove the reference to `REQUEST_URI` but actually `REDIRECT_URL` is no good either. I just tried it and it also contains the original request. But anyway the whole idea makes no sense, whatever is used is only going to contain `index.php` (`SCRIPT_NAME`) since we're trying to pick up an intermediate rewritten URI which there is no need to pass through from the URL processing (and there could be a great many of them). Working with WP is the only way.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think any PHP variable is really suitable/reliable. However, in this particular instance (after the internal rewrite) `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` should contain the `/type/audio` URL (?) - although normally it is not set at all (it's primarily used to read the requested URL when an Apache ErrorDocument is triggered).

Comment: This is my 50c take, similar to what @w3dk said, if the server already processed whatever wp url, any following request (say `domain.com/type/whatever/`) can be rewriten to `domain.com/whatever/`. PS. I am an htaccess beguinner

Comment: @w3dk I tested and it doesn't. Why would it? The URI could have been rewritten dozens of times while being processed, which one should it contain? There is no reason it would contain that one particular rewrite.

Comment: @Omar No, it doesn't work that way. WordPress works off whatever URL is visited, you can't rewrite it internally and have WordPress work on that (you can redirect with R, but that's a completely different thing - an external redirect - and changes what is displayed in the browser). And w3dk agrees with that, you're misunderstanding.

Comment: @SuperDuperApps Hmm, I tested it too and it does! :) `REDIRECT_URL` (set by Apache and passed to PHP) should contain the URL-path of the request prior to the last internal rewrite. If there is no rewrite it's not set. If there is a single rewrite (eg. front controller) then it will be the same as the `REQUEST_URI` (PHP var), but less any query string. If there are multiple rewrites then it's the URL of the _previous_ rewrite. eg. `RewriteRule foo bar [L]` `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` (The `L` flag is reqd). `REQUEST_URI` is `/foo`, but `REDIRECT_URL` is `/bar` (PHP superglobals).

Comment: @user82217 I have no idea what you mean. If you made it work, could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @Omar That wasn't necessarily intended as a realistic solution to this problem if using WordPress. It's probably more _theoretical_ - if you were implementing your own CMS perhaps. I'm sure there is a more WordPress-like way of solving this (as SuperDuperApps suggests). Your current pattern feels wrong - you are trying to manually create "pretty" URLs (or _aliases_) on a system that already manages "pretty" URLs.