# How does wordpress permalink system works?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

Wordpress uses this code in `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

First question, what does the line of code below mean:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Next thing is I don't know how `index.php` handles this. So all URLs are redirected to `index.php`...

If I type this URL:

```
website.pl/One-two-Five
```

`.htaccess` will redirect me to `index.php`:

```
webiste.pl/index.php
```

But there is no information, I mean `QUERY_STRING` or something. It's not something like:

```
website.pl/index.php?data=One-two-Five
```

but instead it is just:

```
website.pl/index.php
```

And this is just `index.php`... So how is `index.php` making this possible? How does WordPress handle this? I can't find any answers. What are the mechanics of WordPress for this?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and one I discussed recently in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43856236/2493235).

As you say, everything (that doesn't exist as a file or directory) is rewritten to `index.php` by:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Regarding the line of code:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

That just prevents any more processing if the URL is already `index.php`. The `-` just says don't change anything and the `[L]` says stop processing this iteration. This is because `.htaccess` rewrite rules will restart processing until there is no change to the URL (so what it does is prevent a file system check on the second run through).

What happens after that is that WordPress examines the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable to see what page was originally requested, and acts on that. That is why it does not need to pass anything through to `index.php` directly in the `.htaccess` file, since the originally requested URL is already available in the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable.

One other point is that these are not redirects, they are rewrites. A redirect is external, going back to the browser. A rewrite is internal only, and does not change the URL for the browser.